# Reading complete metadata from images in Python

Tags: python, image, metadata

I want to read the full list of metadata from images (e.g. jpg) as it is provided for example by ExifTool by Phil Harvey. I cannot use this command line tool and its Python wrapper exiftool due to security restrictions. Unfortunately other Python packages such as PIL only provide a fraction of the available metadata.

Is there any other Python library that provides the full image-metadata as it's returned by ExifTool?

Comment: Not sure what you fear `exiftool` is going to do in your secure environment? Maybe you could contain it in a docker container? Or send your image to a somewhat external container and get back the EXIF data?

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could come to exiftool would be exiv2.  You might try the [exiv2 python interface](https://pypi.org/project/exiv2/).

Answer (score 0):

I tried exiv2, but it also showed only the basic metadata.

The problem with exiftool was that it creates a temp. exe in the user folder, which was blocked by the system. But I found out that the directory can be changed by setting the PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP environment variable.

Another solution is https://oliverbetz.de/pages/Artikel/ExifTool-for-Windows